# Using python with beautiful soup to access a json dictionary - Stocks

Tags: python, json, dictionary, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape stock data and information from bloomberg.com
However, I'm having trouble with using beautiful soup to convert the data into an easily accessible dictionary

It looks like there's a bootstrappedData section under the clientApp variable that fits the json form, and can easily be accessed as a dictionary with python.

So far my code looks like this:

```
def scrape():
    ticker = raw_input("Ticker?")
    market = raw_input("Market?")
    url = "http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/" + ticker + ":" + market
    htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    htmltext = htmlfile.read()
    bs = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
    scripts = str(bs.find_all('script')[-1])
    i = scripts.find("markets/api/quote-page")
    json.dump(scripts[i-3:-12])

print scrape()
```

However this only gets me to the the brackets that make up the bootstrappedData, but how can i make this a dictionary and access the keys and values?. I hope to have an output that looks like

> securityType: Common_Stock
>
> primaryExchange: New York
>
> etc...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ClientApp = require('app/ClientApp');
var clientApp = new ClientApp();
clientApp.start({
environmentConfig: {"appRoot":"","assetManifest":{"public/images/marketdata-quoteshare-image.png":"//assets.bwbx.io/markets/public/images/marketdata-quoteshare-image.31c2f976.png","public/javascripts/application.js":"//assets.bwbx.io/markets/public/javascripts/application.72f7c0c6.js","public/stylesheets/application.css":"//assets.bwbx.io/markets/public/stylesheets/application.922ef728.css","public/stylesheets/when_than.css":"//assets.bwbx.io/markets/public/stylesheets/when_than.d41d8cd9.css"},"clientApp":"app/ClientApp","searchConfig":{"host":"http://search.bloomberg.com"},"sparklineEndpoint":"http://www.bloomberg.com/api/intraday/sparkline/","tracking":{"chartbeat":{"domain":"bloomberg.com","uid":"15087"},"comscore":{"clientId":"3005059","site":"bloomberg","siteIdentifier":"004"},"googleAnalytics":{"gaAccount":"UA-11413116-1"},"personalization":{"site":"","trackingUrl":"http://tracking.bloomberg.com/images/tracking-pixel.gif"}},"featureFlags":{"renderChartsOnClient":true},"watchlist":{"watchlistUrl":"http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/watchlist","sslProxyUrl":"https://login.bloomberg.com/watchlist/markets/watchlist/proxy"},"brisket:wantsCookies":false},
bootstrappedData: {"/markets/api/quote-page/IBM%3AUS":{"securityType":"COMMON_STOCK","basicQuote":{"name":"International Business Machines Corp","primaryExchange":"New York","price":168.95,"issuedCurrency":"USD","priceChange1Day":1.22,"percentChange1Day":0.72736001,"nyPriceTime":"15:02:00.000","nyPriceDate":"2015-06-23","priceMinDecimals":2,"nyTradeStartTime":"09:30:00.000","nyTradeEndTime":"16:30:00.000","timeZoneOffset":-4,"id":"IBM:US"},"detailedQuote":{"priceEarningsRatio":10.05792267,"earningsPerShare":16.780801,"priceMinDecimals":2,"fundamentalDataCurrency":"USD","marketCap":166203415828.26,"issuedCurrency":"USD","sharesOutstanding":984734100,"priceToSalesRatio":1.85375424,"indicatedGrossDividendYield":3.08056861,"bicsSector":"Technology","bicsIndustry":"Technology Services","bicsSubIndustry":"IT Services","openPrice":168.38,"lowPrice":167.573,"highPrice":169.97,"volume":2674483,"previousClosingPriceOneTradingDayAgo":167.73,"lowPrice52Week":149.52,"highPrice52Week":196.4,"totalReturn1Year":-4.686033,"id":"IBM:US"},"priceTimeSeries":[{"id":"IBM:US","price":[{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T13:30:00.000Z","value":167.72},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T13:35:00.000Z","value":167.89},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T13:40:00.000Z","value":167.882},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T13:45:00.000Z","value":168.54},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T13:50:00.000Z","value":168.97},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T13:55:00.000Z","value":169.34},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T14:00:00.000Z","value":169.77},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T14:05:00.000Z","value":169.71},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T14:10:00.000Z","value":169.63},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T14:15:00.000Z","value":169.26},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T14:20:00.000Z","value":169.29},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T14:25:00.000Z","value":169.23},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T14:30:00.000Z","value":169.2},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T14:35:00.000Z","value":169.04},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T14:40:00.000Z","value":168.99},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T14:45:00.000Z","value":169.06},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T14:50:00.000Z","value":169.14},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T14:55:00.000Z","value":169.01},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T15:00:00.000Z","value":169.02},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T15:05:00.000Z","value":169.225},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T15:10:00.000Z","value":169.14},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T15:15:00.000Z","value":169.08},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T15:20:00.000Z","value":168.86},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T15:25:00.000Z","value":168.66},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T15:30:00.000Z","value":168.69},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T15:35:00.000Z","value":168.79},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T15:40:00.000Z","value":168.8384},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T15:45:00.000Z","value":168.83},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T15:50:00.000Z","value":168.78},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T15:55:00.000Z","value":168.69},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T16:00:00.000Z","value":168.66},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T16:05:00.000Z","value":168.54},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T16:10:00.000Z","value":168.49},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T16:15:00.000Z","value":168.5351},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T16:20:00.000Z","value":168.499},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T16:25:00.000Z","value":168.78},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T16:30:00.000Z","value":168.77},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T16:35:00.000Z","value":168.755},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T16:40:00.000Z","value":168.7},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T16:45:00.000Z","value":168.7},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T16:50:00.000Z","value":168.64},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T16:55:00.000Z","value":168.64},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T17:00:00.000Z","value":168.74},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T17:05:00.000Z","value":168.69},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T17:10:00.000Z","value":168.77},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T17:15:00.000Z","value":168.75},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T17:20:00.000Z","value":168.77},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T17:25:00.000Z","value":168.72},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T17:30:00.000Z","value":168.79},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T17:35:00.000Z","value":168.85},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T17:40:00.000Z","value":169.02},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T17:45:00.000Z","value":168.975},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T17:50:00.000Z","value":169.01},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T17:55:00.000Z","value":169.03},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T18:00:00.000Z","value":169.07},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T18:05:00.000Z","value":168.985},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T18:10:00.000Z","value":168.99},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T18:15:00.000Z","value":169.02},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T18:20:00.000Z","value":169.01},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T18:25:00.000Z","value":168.925},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T18:30:00.000Z","value":168.89},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T18:35:00.000Z","value":168.93},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T18:40:00.000Z","value":169.01},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T18:45:00.000Z","value":168.95},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T18:50:00.000Z","value":169.005},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T18:55:00.000Z","value":168.955},{"dateTime":"2015-06-23T19:00:00.000Z","value":168.925}],"dateTimeRanges":{"start":"2015-06-23T13:30:00Z","end":"2015-06-23T20:30:00Z"},"timeZoneOffset":-4,"nyTradeStartTime":"09:30:00.000","nyTradeEndTime":"16:30:00.000","priceMinDecimals":2,"previousClosingPriceOneTradingDayAgo":167.73}],"marketStatus":{"marketStatus":"ACTV","ultimateParentTicker":null,"parentMarketStatus":null,"id":"IBM:US"},"companyNews":{"news":[{"id":"NQD4C46JIJUT01","headline":"IBM‚Äôs Rometty Raises Profile for Women at Sun Valley Confab","publishedAt":"2015-06-22T22:50:36-04:00","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-06-22/ibm-s-rometty-raises-profile-for-women-at-sun-valley-conference","primaryCategory":"technology","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 22, 2015","personalizationTrackingMetaData":"data-resource-type=\"article\" data-resource-id=\"NQD4C46JIJUT01\""},{"id":"NQ7N3CSYF02F01","headline":"Mellanox Battles Intel Aided by Mentalist Who Wowed Kardashian","publishedAt":"2015-06-22T10:04:37-04:00","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-06-20/upstart-battles-intel-with-aid-of-mentalist-who-wowed-kardashian","primaryCategory":"technology","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 22, 2015","personalizationTrackingMetaData":"data-resource-type=\"article\" data-resource-id=\"NQ7N3CSYF02F01\""},{"id":"NQ76QW6KLVRB01","headline":"EBay Sells¬†Back 28.4% Stake in Craigslist, Ending Litigation","publishedAt":"2015-06-19T16:16:03-04:00","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-06-19/ebay-sells-back-28-4-stake-in-craigslist-ending-litigation","primaryCategory":"technology","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 19, 2015","personalizationTrackingMetaData":"data-resource-type=\"article\" data-resource-id=\"NQ76QW6KLVRB01\""},{"id":"NQ3NDSSYF01T01","headline":"Oracle Profit, Sales Miss Estimates","publishedAt":"2015-06-18T16:09:56-04:00","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-06-17/oracle-profit-sales-miss-estimates-on-currency-fluctuations","primaryCategory":"technology","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 18, 2015","personalizationTrackingMetaData":"data-resource-type=\"article\" data-resource-id=\"NQ3NDSSYF01T01\""},{"id":"NQ5GTO6JTSEB01","headline":"1985: The Year Hollywood Discovered Nerds Are Cool","publishedAt":"2015-06-18T13:05:48-04:00","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-06-18/1985-the-year-hollywood-discovered-nerds-are-cool","primaryCategory":"culture","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 18, 2015","personalizationTrackingMetaData":"data-resource-type=\"article\" data-resource-id=\"NQ5GTO6JTSEB01\""},{"id":"NQ573I6VDKHV01","headline":"Wimbledon Follows U.S. Open Golf in Banning Live Video Streaming","publishedAt":"2015-06-18T10:03:01-04:00","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-06-18/wimbledon-follows-u-s-open-golf-in-banning-live-video-streaming","primaryCategory":"industries","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 18, 2015","personalizationTrackingMetaData":"data-resource-type=\"article\" data-resource-id=\"NQ573I6VDKHV01\""},{"id":"NOR89C6JTSEE01","headline":"Microsoft Faces Russian Hurdles as Local Software Thrives","publishedAt":"2015-06-17T11:06:39-04:00","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-06-17/microsoft-oracle-face-russian-hurdles-as-local-software-thrives","primaryCategory":"technology","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 17, 2015","personalizationTrackingMetaData":"data-resource-type=\"article\" data-resource-id=\"NOR89C6JTSEE01\""},{"id":"NPUOUYSYF02E01","headline":"Trash-Talking Rival CEO Vows to Beat IBM on Cybersecurity Deals","publishedAt":"2015-06-15T10:18:00-04:00","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-06-13/trash-talking-rival-ceo-vows-to-beat-ibm-on-cybersecurity-deals","primaryCategory":"technology","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 15, 2015","personalizationTrackingMetaData":"data-resource-type=\"article\" data-resource-id=\"NPUOUYSYF02E01\""},{"id":"NPU7FGSYF01S01","headline":"London Tech Week Seeks to Boost U.S. Investment in Startups","publishedAt":"2015-06-15T05:34:23-04:00","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-06-15/london-tech-week-seeks-to-boost-800-million-of-u-s-investment","primaryCategory":"technology","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 15, 2015","personalizationTrackingMetaData":"data-resource-type=\"article\" data-resource-id=\"NPU7FGSYF01S01\""},{"id":"NPUEXTSYF01T01","headline":"IBM to Invest ‚ÄòHundreds of Millions‚Äô in Free Data Technology","publishedAt":"2015-06-15T00:01:00-04:00","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2015-06-15/ibm-to-invest-hundreds-of-millions-in-free-data-technology-iaxdikxe","primaryCategory":"technology","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 15, 2015","personalizationTrackingMetaData":"data-resource-type=\"article\" data-resource-id=\"NPUEXTSYF01T01\""}],"id":"IBM:US"},"companyVideos":{"news":[{"id":"NQ0CU96JIJUT","headline":"Alibaba's Netflix Strategy: Bloomberg West (06/15)","publishedAt":"2015-06-15T22:51:45.396Z","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/videos/2015-06-15/alibaba-s-netflix-strategy-bloomberg-west-06-15-","primaryCategory":"technology","thumbnail":"http://www.bloomberg.com/image/ijBRVETIQSyc.jpg","duration":"22:39"},{"id":"NQ08S46K50XT","headline":"Why IBM Wants to Bring Spark Mainstream","publishedAt":"2015-06-15T21:24:04.605Z","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/videos/2015-06-15/why-ibm-wants-to-bring-spark-mainstream","primaryCategory":"technology","thumbnail":"http://www.bloomberg.com/image/iHtcdxtkdyr8.jpg","duration":"4:12"},{"id":"NPZHIG6TTDSB","headline":"Coming Next in Business: The On-Demand Sales Force","publishedAt":"2015-06-15T11:35:04.804Z","url":"http://www.bloomberg.com/news/videos/2015-06-15/coming-next-in-business-the-on-demand-sales-force","primaryCategory":"technology","thumbnail":"http://www.bloomberg.com/image/i8g9QeyWJyjE.jpg","duration":"2:38"}],"id":"IBM:US"},"pressReleases":{"pressReleases":[{"id":"a00WmfzBs93w","headline":"IBM Studio - Groningen to Create Data-Driven Digital Experiences for Clients ","publishedAt":"2015-06-23T11:00:05-04:00","publishedAtDisplay":"11:00 AM","url":"http://bloomberg.com/article/2015-06-23/a00WmfzBs93w.html"},{"id":"aoJ6HOi9D7I4","headline":"IBM Readies Brands to Capture New Sales Opportunities Driven By Unexpected Spikes in Traffic ","publishedAt":"2015-06-23T10:00:05-04:00","publishedAtDisplay":"10:00 AM","url":"http://bloomberg.com/article/2015-06-23/aoJ6HOi9D7I4.html"},{"id":"azp4qWIDSEn4","headline":"IBM and Bon Appetit Serve Up Chef Watson for All ","publishedAt":"2015-06-23T09:00:10-04:00","publishedAtDisplay":"9:00 AM","url":"http://bloomberg.com/article/2015-06-23/azp4qWIDSEn4.html"},{"id":"adGtRAm_6qXY","headline":"IBM Delivers Docker Based Container Services for Enterprise Cloud Application Developers ","publishedAt":"2015-06-22T13:00:03-04:00","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 22, 2015","url":"http://bloomberg.com/article/2015-06-22/adGtRAm_6qXY.html"},{"id":"adGbY6bR6dRY","headline":"Photo Release -- Nidec and IBM Japan to Jointly Develop IoT Technology for Better Production Rate and Shorter Downtime of ","publishedAt":"2015-06-22T02:30:07-04:00","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 22, 2015","url":"http://bloomberg.com/article/2015-06-22/adGbY6bR6dRY.html"},{"id":"aPlFLiFFVbOk","headline":"As Hurricane Season Approaches, IBM and The Weather Company Collaborate on Emergency Management for Cities ","publishedAt":"2015-06-22T00:01:02-04:00","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 22, 2015","url":"http://bloomberg.com/article/2015-06-22/aPlFLiFFVbOk.html"},{"id":"aGWiLanx93X0","headline":"IBM Brings One of the World's Largest Networks of More Than a Billion Law Enforcement Shareable Documents to the Cloud ","publishedAt":"2015-06-22T00:01:01-04:00","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 22, 2015","url":"http://bloomberg.com/article/2015-06-22/aGWiLanx93X0.html"},{"id":"aMn.1xd9pm60","headline":"IBM and Sogeti Forge Alliance to Accelerate Hybrid Cloud Development ","publishedAt":"2015-06-18T11:40:01-04:00","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 18, 2015","url":"http://bloomberg.com/article/2015-06-18/aMn.1xd9pm60.html"},{"id":"aRvHe.JJK3jo","headline":"Wimbledon and IBM Push Digital Boundaries to Enhance Fan and Player Engagement ","publishedAt":"2015-06-18T09:00:06-04:00","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 18, 2015","url":"http://bloomberg.com/article/2015-06-18/aRvHe.JJK3jo.html"},{"id":"aDiABLcYzRNM","headline":"ZeroTurnaround Integrates With Solutions From IBM, Red Hat, SAP and AWS to Simplify Development and Testing in the Cloud ","publishedAt":"2015-06-18T08:50:00-04:00","publishedAtDisplay":"Jun 18, 2015","url":"http://bloomberg.com/article/2015-06-18/aDiABLcYzRNM.html"}],"id":"IBM:US"},"boardMembers":{"boardMembers":[],"count":14,"id":"IBM:US"},"executives":{"executives":[{"id":"3970902","name":"Virginia M Rometty \"Ginni\"","title":"Chairman/President/CEO","slug":"/3970902-virginia-m-rometty"},{"id":"3320296","name":"Steven A Mills \"Steve\"","title":"Exec VP:Software & Systems","slug":"/3320296-steven-a-mills"},{"id":"15091767","name":"Martin J Schroeter","title":"Senior VP/CFO","slug":"/15091767-martin-j-schroeter"},{"id":"19076604","name":"Arvind Krishna","title":"Senior VP/Dir:Research","slug":"/19076604-arvind-krishna"},{"id":"1857778","name":"John E Kelly","title":"Senior VP:Solutions Portfolio","slug":"/1857778-john-e-kelly"}],"count":22,"id":"IBM:US"},"profile":{"description":"International Business Machines Corporation (IBM) provides computer solutions through the use of advanced information technology. The Company's solutions include technologies, systems, products, services, software, and financing. IBM offers its products through its global sales and distribution organization, as well as through a variety of third party distributors and resellers.","address":["One New Orchard Road","Armonk, NY 10504-1722","United States"],"phone":"1-914-499-1900","website":"www.ibm.com","id":"IBM:US"},"chartDefaultTimeFrame":"1_DAY"}}
});
</script>
```

Comment: what is `pattern` for?

Comment: Oh, sorry I left it in there by accident from trying something new

Answer (score 0):

Simple as

```
import json
for line in scrape().split('\n'):
  if (line.startswith('bootstrappedData: ')):
    jsonStr = line.replace('bootstrappedData: ', '')
    dataDict = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

I do, however, have my doubts about whether you really want to do this. That JSON may or may not be useful to you, and furthermore, it's very subject to change. Depending on what you're looking for using an API is much more reliable than scraping.

Comment: Ok, that helps a lot. If I wanted to print certain keys and values in this data dict should I not use JSON then? If so, what should I use instead. I'm not sure I know how to use an API.

Comment: No, if that's all you want, the final line of this code, `json.loads`, gives you a Python dictionary/array structure matching the JSON. I was just warning that scraping a site for data like this in unreliable in the long-term. There are plenty of tutorials online about APIs, but the catch is that most aren't free and/or have rate-limiting.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the help and advice. I'll take a look at whether there are any APIs suitable for my purposes.